# JAVA how to store mysql login details

Tags: java, mysql, security

**Environment**

I have a `java` application that is going to need access to a `mysql` database to load and save data and the load/save cannot occur by writing to disk, so it has to be through the database.

I was reading about `JNDI` but I'm not sure that will help because every example I've seen has been for a `java servlet` and my goal is to use it in a `java` standalone application.

**Questions**

- What is the best way to store the `mysql` username and password so that all clients can access the database but still protecting the login information so that my program is not decompiled and someone uses the `mysql` login to drop my all my tables?
- What would you guys recommend? I'd like this to be secure as possible and I'm open to any suggestions.
- Only a handful of statements will be executed on the database and those are hard coded strings that are used in prepared statements so I think that is secure or no?
- But my main issue is protecting the database login information.

Comment: @AnoopLL then someone uses a Java decompiler and get the connection string with all credentials? No way.

Comment: store user information in the database. have your own db info saved in xml. on login check it compare to the user to the db for grant access

Comment: is creating a webservice an option ?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- use credentials with the minimum possible permissions. That means this user will be able to INSERT but not DROP or DELETE
- separate the program and the code that writes to the database by creating a webservice (or other remoting techniques)
- use only PROCEDUREs and FUNCTIONs to contact the database and grant only them to the user. By doing this you will have a login to the database that is not allowed to do anything except calling procedures and functions.

Comment: I like the first option that seems super easy and slightly secure but still I'd have a database full of garbage data if someone decided to flood it and could possibly result in a denial of service even.   What should I look up to get more information on the remoting techniques you talked about?

Comment: @Mkey the remoting will not save you from dos attacks either. Either protect your Webservice with per app credentials or implement sanity checks for the incoming data

Comment: What do you mean by per app credentials?  My idea was to have a .xml file with the login details that is stored so the outside world cannot view it, but then how could I make my application be able to get the login details from it?

Comment: @Mkey I meant that users of your app could each get their own credentials to authenticate with your webservice

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the options that @Marged provided you could also encrypt and store the credentials in your code.  See encrypt + decrypt examples here [Encrypt and decrypt a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487525/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-in-java).  This will hide the credentials from any decompiler.

Going with a web service option is a more serious approach and requires a lot more effort and cost to implement and then you need to secure these.

Comment: I was looking into the web service option and that seems the most viable since wouldn't a determined person still be able to see the decrypted string in memory if they had enough free time and the right tools?    I know I'd still have to secure the web server, but where would i start? I mean what should I google/read about to get started on creating a web service that can handle this?

Comment: You will have to put the decryption code into your program so a decompiler will show that too, which makes that solution not a 100% secure

Comment: @Marged - agreed, it is still possible to get it out but it does require a much more serious level of decompiling and debugging.

Comment: @Mkey - As I said web services requires a lot more effort and cost.  This  http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/what-is-spring-ws.html might be a good place to start.

Comment: @Mkey you might want to consider Spring boot, see this for examples: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Comment: @MikeMurphy unless you take extra measures like obfuscators all you need is jd-gui and you get the complete sourcecode of the encryption routine. Too easy for savvy users.