# How to encrypt data in playframework 2.0 java?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have created a template, in which i want to encrypt few details before saving that form to the database. Every other details can be stored as plain text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205135/how-to-encrypt-string-in-java

Answer (score 2):

AES encryption/decryption is incorporated in version 2.1 of Play. If you don't want to use unstable version of framework you'll need to wait for its final publishing or make changes in your version manually. See [this Lighthouse's ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/574-crypto-interface-incomplete-compared-to-play-1x)

Answer (score 1):

First of all Ebean support [Encryption](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/encryption.html), so perhaps this solves your problem. Furthermore feel free to use my [Crypto-Implementation](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~opensource21/permsec/psec2.0.x/view/head:/psec/app/de/ppi/util/Crypto.java), it quite easy.

Comment: i think you can't use Ebean encrypting because you can't set advanced setting for Ebean in play 2.0. at least source : [link](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/156-add-support-for-ebeanproperties)