# java.lang.NumberFormatException or java.nio.BufferUnderflowException when transforming bytes

Tags: utf-8, binary, byte

I played around with some String -> byte -> binary code and I want my code to work for any byte[] array, currently it only works for, I am not sure ascii?

chinese DONT WORK.

```
String message =" 汉语";
    playingWithFire(message.getBytes());
```

while String wow = "WOW..."; Works :( I want it to work for all utf-8 formates. Any pointers on how I can do it?

//thanks

```
public static byte[] playingWithFire(byte[] bytes){
    byte[] newbytes = null;

        newbytes = new byte[bytes.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
            String tempStringByte = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');

            StringBuffer newByteBrf = null;

                newByteBrf = new StringBuffer();
                for(int x = 0; x < tempStringByte.length(); x++){
                    newByteBrf.append(tempStringByte.charAt(x));
                }
                /*short a = Short.parseShort(newByteBrf.toString(), 2);
                ByteBuffer bytesads = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(a);
                newbytes[i] = bytesads.get();
                cause: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
                */
                //cause: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range.
                newbytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(newByteBrf.toString(), 2);

            }
    return newbytes;
}
```

Comment: The Java `char` type holds Unicode characters. When moving between `char` and 'byte` you need a suitible encoder to let the byte array be one of the useful encodings. (e.g. Big5, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.) So store as byte but manipulate as char.

Comment: How should I use: Charset encoding = Charset.forName("UTF-16");? Ofc I have to use it like this message.getBytes(encoding) but it still donst solv the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

`message.getBytes()` in your case is trying to convert Chinese Unicode characters to bytes using the default character set on your computer. If its a western charset, its going to be wrong.

Notice that `String.getBytes()` has another form with `String.getBytes(String)` where the string is the name of a character encoding that is used to convert the chars of the string to bytes.

The `char` type will hold Unicode. The `byte` type only holds raw bits in groups of 8.

So, to convert a Unicode string to bytes encoded as UTF-16 you would use this code:

```
String message =" 汉语";
byte[] utf16Bytes = message.getBytes("utf-16");
```

Substitute the name of any encoding that you want to use.

Similarly `new String(String, byte[])` constructor can take an array of bytes encoded in some fashion and, given the String, can convert those bytes to Unicode characters.

For example: If you want to convert those bytes, which were encoded as utf-16 above, back to a `String` (which has Unicode `char`s in it):

```
String newMessage = new String(utf16Bytes, "utf-16");
```

Since I don't know what you mean by "binary code" above, I can't go much farther. As I see it, the Unicode chars have a binary code inside them that represents the characters one-by-one. Also the byte array has a binary code in it that represents the characters with a many-bytes-to-one-character representation. If you want to encrypt the byte array somehow, use a standard, proven encryption method and proven, time-tested procedures to secure the contents.

Comment: Note, my problem is why I cant convert a String binary that is representing ex, 汉语 to a byte / byte[].

Comment: I know a standard way to encrypt the content so I only need to be able to transform the bytes in some way. If you have a bettery way of transforming the byte[] into binary repreentation please share it. Or if you know a way to transform the binary representation back into a byte[] :)

Comment: Notice how in this question's answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205135/how-to-encrypt-string-in-java) how they always start with a byte array (or a string they convert to a byte array). If you change to byte array to binary and then back to bytes, it's just going in a circle. You have a byte array with the data, just use it as is.