# How can I store text in java in unreadable format and how can I retrieve it back?

Tags: java, file, io

How can I store text in java in unreadable format and how can I retrieve it back?
I mean The saved file should be as XYZ.fcx (or any format) Which is not readable. Don't suggest me to simply change the extension of file. 

I'm doing project So please give your comments fast.

thank you!

Comment: Unreadable on what platform? and to whom? More detail please

Comment: Ureadable for someone opening the file? Or for someone whoe really ones to read it? If the first one you could serialize it and save it, if the second one, you need to encrypt it.

Comment: Unreadable for a simple user on any platform. Suppose on Windows Platform. Doll.txt is readable but I want to save my files in Some Other format which would not understandable for simple users.

Comment: try googling something about encryption. Fast.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypt your data in the file for example with AES.

You can look it up here: [How to encrypt String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205135/how-to-encrypt-string-in-java)

Just chaning the file extension may not help because you can force to open the file in a text editor. In my optinion encryption is the savest way