# How can I check the result of encryption (SHA1PRNG and AES) in Java?

Tags: java, aes, sha1

I made a class which has a method to encrypt data using SHA1PRNG and AES algorithm.

```
public String encrypt(String str, String pw) throws Exception{ 
    byte[] bytes = pw.getBytes();
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(bytes);
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");    
    kgen.init(128,sr);

    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getEncoded(),"AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(str.getBytes());
    return Hex.encodeHexString(encrypted); 
}
```

I used this method in my main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Encrytion enc = new Encrytion();  //my class name has a typo :(
    enc.encrypt("abcde", "abcdfg");
    System.out.println(enc);

}
```

My result is

> com.dsmentoring.kmi.Encrytion@34340fab

just my packagename + class name +  and some number ( I'm guessing this is reference address to the actual data?)

I want to see the result of my encryption like 'a13efx34123fdv....... ' like this.  What do I need to add in my main method?  Any advice?

Comment: You are printing the instance rather than the value it returns

Comment: @karthick How can I print the value?   I tried to print 'str' or 'pw' or 'decrypted' but can't figure out how

Comment: Just a few feedback. Java 8 onwards, you should use `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` instead of `SHA1PRNG`. `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` defaults to ECB mode which is not secured. You should ideally use an authenticated encryption mode like GCM. You should avoid storing password in `String` as `String` is immutable and you can't clear it. Therefore in heap dumps it may appear. You should also clear `SecretKey` and `SecretKeySpec` after use. I recommend that you read. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015144/1235935 for complete Java implementation

Comment: @Saptarshi Basu   Thank you so much. It is very helpful~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing the `Encryption` object instead of the result of the function call.
You can do this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Encrytion enc = new Encrytion();  //my class name has a typo :(
    String result = enc.encrypt("abcde", "abcdfg");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```