# How to generate a AES 128 bit key in Java. I want something like this. Es8NxqG/f3VMzcd9mrPSQQ==

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I tried below.

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128);
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
String s = new String(skey.getEncoded());
```

But not getting in the required format.
Would really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to the key generation section here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015144/1235935 Once you get the key bytes, encode it in Base64. The answer for Base64 encoding is also provided in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

> skey.getEncoded()

`getEncoded` method returns a byte array. You cannot just create a String from byte array, most of the bytes would represent non-printable characters.

What you ask for is Base64 encoding - it is a way to represent binary data as printable character.

You can use the default Java Base64 encoder 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html to encode and decode binary data.

```
String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(skey.getEncoded());
```

There are other encoder implementations used as well, such as [commons-codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.11/apidocs/index.html)

Please note - in crypto all primitives and operations (keys, encryption, digest, signing, ..) are working on top of byte arrays, encoding is used only to represent data as printable string